# Why is my makefile not generating object files?

Tags: c++, makefile

Here is my makefile:

```
LIBS = libxml2.so.2.9.4 
LDFLAGS = -lstdc++ -lpthread -lxml2

vpath %.hpp ./
vpath %.cpp ./
vpath %.h ./libxml2/include/libxml

all: KeyGenerator

KeyGenerator: main.o ProjectXmlParser.o xmlparser.o
    g++ ${CXXFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -o KeyGenerator $+ ${LIBS}

main.o: main.cpp

ProjectXmlParser.o: ProjectXmlParser.cpp ProjectXmlParser.hpp

xmlparser.o: xmlparser.cpp xmlparser.hpp global.hpp

phony:  clean

clean: 
        rm -f *.o
```

The output:

```
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
g++ -g -Wall -std=gnu++11 -pthread -I./ -I./src -I./libxml2/include -lstdc++ -lpthread -lxml2 -o KeyGenerator main.o ProjectXmlParser.o xmlparser.o libxml2.so.2.9.4 
g++: error: ProjectXmlParser.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: xmlparser.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'KeyGenerator' failed
make: *** [KeyGenerator] Error 1
```

In the project directory all of my hpp and cpp files exist at the same level. I do have one additional project called libxml that I am using. When I do a build main.o is created but none of the .o files are created. I've seen other posts pose this question but so far nothing has worked for me.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't defined a recipe for how to create the object files

Comment: Which line in your makefile do you expect to trigger generation of the missing .o file and how?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `vpath` directives?

Comment: @Jacob GNU Make uses [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) for that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I comment out the vpath directives I get the same output.

Comment: Based on the information you've provided you shouldn't get this error, which means something is wrong that you haven't told us about.  Either the makefile here is different in some material way from your actual makefile, or there's something quite odd.  You showed us the error message but you didn't show the compile lines make ran; those can be very helpful.  Also, you can run `make -d` and examine the output looking for how make treats the `ProjectXmlParser.o` file.

Comment: @MadScientist Here is the output of a make -d: https://pastebin.com/eMuDDAkG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the `make -d` output:

```
Must remake target 'ProjectXmlParser.o'.
Successfully remade target file 'ProjectXmlParser.o'.
```

it seems that make thinks you have an empty recipe to build this target.  Maybe you have some stray TAB characters in your makefile after the `ProjectxXmlParser.o` and `xmlparser.o` rules, that aren't shown in the makefile you pasted into this question?

Comment: Yep... There was a tab on the blank line between  
xmlparser.o: xmlparser.cpp xmlparser.hpp global.hpp and phony: clean

Comment: Which can be seen when editing the question. Good catch!

Comment: I VERY much appreciate you.